# About the degree of a tensor power of a line bundle on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose that $H$ is a hyperplane in some $n$ dimensional complex projective space 
and $C$ is a smooth curve of positive genus. Can I say that $\deg((H|_C)^{\otimes 2}) = 2\deg(H|_C)$?

Comment: The degree is a homomorphism from the group of line bundles to $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree of a line bundle $L$ on a curve $C$ is $\operatorname{deg}(L) = \langle c_1(L), [C]\rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$. As $c_1(L\otimes L') = c_1(L) + c_1(L')$, we have

\begin{align*}
\deg(L\otimes L') &= \langle c_1(L\otimes L'), [C]\rangle\\ 
&= \langle c_1(L) + c_1(L'), [C]\rangle\\
&= \langle c_1(L), [C]\rangle + \langle c_1(L'), [C]\rangle\\ 
&= \deg(L) + \deg(L').
\end{align*}

In particular, $\deg(L^{\otimes 2}) = 2\deg(L)$.